# Targeting CSS code for only Iphone5 in chrome

Tags: html, css, iphone, google-chrome

i have done the website it is working fine in all the mobile devices but in Iphone5 the font size not accepting. it is bigger and bolded than what i have give in css code. below the code i have given for common

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
```

so i want any specific code do i need to add for IPHONE 5. thanks

Comment: `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%`

Comment: You say **it is working fine in all the mobile devices except iphone5**; can you please post your mobile media query? If you edit your question and add it in there we can see what you have already declared.

Comment: hi this is the code i have written for                                                   @media screen (max-width:640px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
p{font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;}
}

Comment: 640px screen size is too big and will not target an iPhone 5 - this is why your media query isn't working, please see my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to target mobile devices, you will need to make sure you have the following in your header:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

And then add the mobile media query in your stylesheet:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    /* Add mobile specific styles here */
}
```

I know in your question you want to target only an iphone5, however it is a good idea to add one media query to target all mobile devices and you won't have any issues and can add styles for mobile only within said media query.

**Edited Answer**

```
/* iPhone 4/5 portrait mode */
@media (max-width:320px) { 
   p {
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
     font-size: 14px; 
     line-height: 20px;
   } 
}

/* iPhone 4/5 landscape mode */
@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
   */ Styles go in here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this medai query for iPhone 5 only

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

Comment: hi thanks for you reply, still seems to be a issue in Iphone5

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the best way to do this, but you can set styles in js/jQuery when detecting iphone.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
    if (agentID) {
      /*set some style here*/
    }
});
```

Also, if your text is too big on iphone, you can try:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 90%;
```

Anyway, Helvetica Nue is not standard font, so if you won't use external fonts import, they can look diffrent on some devices.